# How to update django auth User using a custom form

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am using Django's built in authentication to manage users on a social media website. I am using a one-to-one relationship to attach a profile to each user. I can update all the parts of the profile I have attached using an UpdateView. However I don't know how to do that with Django's built in User. So I created a form that uses the _meta class.  I have gotten to the point where my form will add a new user instead of update the current one. I was hoping one of you could help me fix my code. Thanks in advance for any help you can offer

views.py

```py
class PrivProfileUpdate(View):
    form_class = UserUpdateForm
    template_name = 'user/user_form.html'

    #display a blank form
    def get(self, request, pk):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    #proces form data
    def post(self, request, pk):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        if form.is_valid():

            user = form.save(commit=True)

            print("we are trying to save")
            #cleaned (normalized) data
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            user.set_password(password) #this is the only way to change a password because of hashing
            user.save()

        return render(request, self.template_name,{'form': form})
```

forms.py

```py
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

**SOLUTION:**

in views.py

```py
class PrivProfileUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserUpdateForm
    template_name = 'user/user_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save(commit=True)
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return redirect('user:index')
```

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing special about the User class here. Just as with any other model, to update an existing instance you pass it as the `instance` argument to the form.

However, you do not actually need to do this at all yourself. You should be using an UpdateView, which does this for you; then you do not need to define `get` and `post`. The only method you need to define here is `form_valid`, to set the password:

```
class PrivProfileUpdate(UpdateView):
    form_class = UserUpdateForm
    template_name = 'user/user_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save(commit=True)
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: thanks, I had to change a couple things to get it working. For those that run into this problem I have the fix above. Also thank you Daniel, I don't have enough rep to give you a point.